# Mongodb set and unset operations in a single query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have documents in which I would like to update the hostUser with one of the members of the document,also have to delete the record from the member document and add the chips of the deleted member in the club chips.

Here is the sample document.

```
{
    "_id" : "1002",
    "hostUser" : "1111111111",
    "clubChips" : 10000,
    "requests" : {},
    "profile" : {
        "clubname" : "AAAAA",
        "image" : "0"
    },
    "tables" : [ 
        "SJCA3S0Wm"
    ],
    "isDeleted" : false,
    "members" : {
        "1111111111" : {
            "chips" : 0,
            "id" : "1111111111"
        },
        "2222222222" : {
            "chips" : 0,
            "id" : "2222222222"
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried.

```
db.getCollection('test').updateMany({"hostUser":"1111111111"},
{"$set":{"hostUser":"2222222222"},"$unset":{"members.1111111111":""}})
```

Comment: If also if I could check if the values exist in the member field would be an add-on.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would handle unset and set in a single call to updateMany. Can you please clarify what you meant by "check if the values exist in the member field"?

```
db.getCollection('test').updateMany(
    {"hostUser":"1111111111"},
    {
        '$set': {"hostUser":"2222222222"} ,
        '$unset': {"members.1111111111":""}
    }
)
```

Comment: The solution that you gave that I have already tried.I also wanted to check if there exist memerbs.2222222222